# How to get elevation and magnetic field in iOS

Tags: ios, cmmotionmanager

Im trying to get the elevation value and magnetic field value in iOS. I have been googling long time about those subjects, but I couldnt find anything that works properly.

a) When im talking about elevation value, I want to get the angle in degrees when im moving the top of my mobile up. I have attached a image to make it easier.
I have been trying like that, but it doesn't work:

.h

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@property (nonatomic, retain) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
```

.m

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
[self.motionManager startMagnetometerUpdates];
NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:myQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error){
    float degrees = (motion.attitude.roll*180) / M_PI;
    NSLog(@"Value of elevation is: %f", degrees);
}];
```

b) About magnetic field, I want to get the impact of devices, magnets, iron, etc that affect the accuracy of my mobile.
* All the values im getting are not correct by this solution (inside of a kind of NSTimer):

```
NSLog(@"magnetometer data -> x: %f", self.motionManager.magnetometerData.magneticField.x);
NSLog(@"magnetometer data -> y: %f", self.motionManager.magnetometerData.magneticField.y);
NSLog(@"magnetometer data -> z: %f", self.motionManager.magnetometerData.magneticField.z);

float magneticField = sqrtf( powf(self.motionManager.magnetometerData.magneticField.x, 2) 
+ powf(self.motionManager.magnetometerData.magneticField.y, 2) + 
powf(self.motionManager.magnetometerData.magneticField.z, 2) );

NSLog(@"magneticField value: %@", magneticField.text);
```

Any ideas how to figure out....Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer to both questions. Here is the code I am using it. Hope it can help to someone.

MagneticField:
.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

.m

```
@synthesize locationManager;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Starting compass setup
if(locationManager == nil)
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;

//Start the compass updates.
if (CLLocationManager.headingAvailable) {
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"No Heading Available: ");
    UIAlertView *noCompassAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Compass!" message:@"This device does not have the ability to measure magnetic fields." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [noCompassAlert show];
}
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
NSLog(@"Magnetic value: %@", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", sqrt(newHeading.x*newHeading.x + newHeading.y*newHeading.y + newHeading.z*newHeading.z)] stringByAppendingFormat:@" µT"]);
}
```

Elevation:
.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
```

.m

```
@synthesize motionManager;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Initializating MotionManager Object    
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = YES;
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 20.0/60.0;

// Getting Elevation Value
CMDeviceMotionHandler  motionHandler = ^ (CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    CMAttitude *a = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;
    NSLog(@"Elevation value, %@:", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", a.pitch*180/M_PI] stringByAppendingFormat:@"˚"]);
};
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:motionHandler];
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hi rubrin
Thanks for post your answer for finding elevation.
I just want to know in which format the elevation value i will find?